# UIImageview in custom UITableViewCell not correctly displayed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a custom UITableViewCell.

```
class ProductRow: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var iconStack: UIStackView!
@IBOutlet weak var prdImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var prdPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var prdTitle: UILabel!


override func awakeFromNib()
{
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

I load the UIImageView via extension

```
extension UIImageView {
public func imageFromUrl(urlString: String)
{
    let myUrl = URL(string: "https://" + MobMenu.domain + "/" + MobMenu.shop + "/prd/" + urlString);

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: myUrl!)
    {
        data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else
        {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async
        {
            self.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }

    }
    task.resume()
}
}
```

I update the fields in the row via the tableview function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! ProductRow

    let prdDTO = prdList[indexPath.row];

    //getURLImage(img : prdDTO.getPrdImg(), myCell : myCell)

    myCell.prdTitle.text = prdDTO.getPrdTitle()
    myCell.prdTitle.font =  UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 12)
    myCell.prdPrice.text = prdDTO.getPrice()

    myCell.prdImage.imageFromUrl(urlString: prdDTO.getPrdImg())
    myCell.prdImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    myCell.prdImage.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

The problem is this line of code myCell.prdImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit. Everything is as it should be if I remove it but if I remove it, the resulting image will be too big. If I leave it in there however the images gets pushed down the tableview

[Image of app here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4sWa.png)

I spent many hours googling it but could not figure the problem. Please help. Many thanks

Comment: are there any constraints for UIImageView?

Comment: Yes. there are 4.

Comment: width = 0.5 of superview width
trailing spaces to prdTitle, prdPrice and iconStack

Comment: put a container UIView with same constraints then add UIImageView with (0,0,0,0) frame.
maybe it works

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help! Turns out it was the constraints. Did not set a height for image. Gods constraints suck.

Answer (score 0):

well first i suggest you try to give aspect to fit in the definition of the custom cell class.
you should also turn  AutoTranslatingMasks to false and set the constraints yourself.
if the size of image is not too big then you should choose

```
image.renderingMode.alwaysOriginal
```

so that UITableViewCell dont change it